# AutoFilter Macro to hide 0 and blank values

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to hide rows in a particular column with zero values and blank values after clicking a button. I have coded the following macro:

`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$16:$C$2106").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlFilterValues`

It correctly filters 0 values. However, it is not filtering about blank cells. Is this the correct code?

Answer (score 2):

You could try two criteria:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$16:$C$2106").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="*"
```

***Noteworthy:*** It's [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to try and stay away from using `ActiveSheet` and the likes.

Comment: I attempted this and it did not work as intended. It ended up hiding rows that had values

Comment: @90'sProSkater, that's strange. Works as intended on my end. Maybe update your question with some of your sample data/screenshot etc.

Comment: Criteria2 should be set to "<>" to filter out blanks as per @Jan's example below. As written, Criteria2:="*" filters out everything and you're left with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with JvdV, two operators is the way to go.  For filtering out zero and blank (empty) you may want:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$16:$C$2106").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"
```

Since edits must be at least 6 characters, edited Criteria2 to use named parameter syntax. Changed Criteria2="<>" to Criteria2:="<>"

Comment: Post-edit comment: @Jan's code worked. My mistake was not fully clearing the existing AutoFilter. `    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("QuizResults")
        If Not .AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
`